# Como retornar todas as colunas de uma pesquisa trazendo apenas aquelas com maior data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso obter o seguinte retorno:

> ```
> Id    |CodCliente | Data      |Valor
> 47    |27         |2021-01-06 |58140000.00
> 72    |3          |2021-01-11 |18224000.00
> ```

```
declare @tab1 table (
    Id int,
    CodCliente int,
    Data date,
    Valor decimal(18,2)
)

insert into @tab1 (Id, CodCliente, Data, Valor) values (    47, 25, '01/12/2020',   64260000.00 )
insert into @tab1 (Id, CodCliente, Data, Valor) values (    47, 27, '01/06/2021',   58140000.00 )
insert into @tab1 (Id, CodCliente, Data, Valor) values (    72, 3,  '01/11/2021',   18224000.00 )
insert into @tab1 (Id, CodCliente, Data, Valor) values (    72, 11, '01/12/2020',   5100000.00  )

select Id, CodCliente, Data, Valor from @tab1

Id  |CodCliente | Data      |Valor
47  |25         |2020-01-12 |64260000.00
47  |27         |2021-01-06 |58140000.00
72  |3          |2021-01-11 |18224000.00
72  |11         |2020-01-12 |5100000.00
```

Tentei fazer algo assim mas não desse jeito não me retorna todas as colunas que preciso conforme citado no inicio:

```
select Id, Max(Data) as Data from @tab1 group by Id

Id  | Data      
47  |2021-01-06 
72  |2021-01-11
```

Comment: select * from @tab1 t1 where t1.Data  = (select Max(t2Data) as Data from where t2.Id = t1.Id)

Comment: @Motta funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O exemplo do [@Motta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5005/motta) funcionou adequadamente:

```
select * from @tab1 t1 where t1.Data = (select Max(t2Data) as Data from where t2.Id = t1.Id)
```

Comment: Mas atente ao que disse o @Wagner Faria ...

Answer (score 1):

Algumas coisas pra dizer a respeito da sua pergunta.

1º tu criou o campo ID que normalmente é a chave primaria. Esse campo não pode repetir valor

2º Tu nomeou um campo como "Data" ... isso ai é palavra reservada. Pra evitar problemas, tenta colocar nas próximas vezes o que o campo representa. Ex: data_nascimento.

Lista de palavras reservadas: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

3º Vou considerar que tu quer trazer simplesmente os 2 resultados com data mais recente. Nesse caso tu pode usar o comando LIMIT

```
select * from @tab1 t 
order by t.data desc
limit 2
```

Comment: Olá @Wagner Faria obrigado pela sua resposta, porém não funcionou sobre o ID e DATA coloquei assim apenas para simplificar o código e torná-lo mais didático até porque não é o foco.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa para esse tipo de caso é utilizar uma função de classificação (nesse caso a row_number):

```
with CTE_RN as
(
    select 
        Id, 
        CodCliente, 
        Data, 
        Valor, 
        row_number() over(partition by Id order by Data desc) as RN
    from @tab1
)

select 
    Id, 
    CodCliente, 
    Data, 
    Valor 
from CTE_RN
where 
    RN = 1
```